# TS Concepts - advantages of concept with brackets

Tags: c++, c++-concepts, c++-ts

Could anybody explain me **why** this two (slightly) different code snippets work similarily?
Is there *any* advantage of using one over the other?

#### #1 One way

```
template<typename T>
concept bool Swappable = requires (T a, T b) {
    {std::swap(a, b)} -> void;
};
```

#### #2 Other way

```
template<typename T>
concept bool Swappable() {
    return requires(T a, T b) {
        {std::swap(a, b)} -> void;
    };
};
```

What's the reason the second example has **Swappable** with brackets and returns "requirements"?

Possible main:

```
int main() {
    static_assert(Swappable<int>, "NOT SWAPPABLE!"); // Compiles when #1
    // static_assert(Swappable<int>(), "NOT SWAPPABLE!"); // Compiles when #2

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Both are Concepts TS syntax. Neither is compatible with C++20.

Comment: Corrected C++20 to Technical Specifications